# Filemaker xml output via xslt with column names

Tags: xslt, filemaker

I am new to xslt programming and xlm.  I have created the code below this works fine, except that instead variable names for each column, it just shows "colno"  How do I get the column names into the output?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fmp"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="kMetaData" select="fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD"/>
  <xsl:variable name="colno"   
    select="count($kMetaData[following-sibling::fmp:FIELD/@NAME]) + 1" />

  <xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT">
    <PERSON>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW" />
    </PERSON>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fmp:ROW">
    <ELEMENTS>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="fmp:COL" />
     </ELEMENTS>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fmp:COL">

    <xsl:element name="colno">
      <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to make some suggestion without input xml. But at first sight this `<xsl:element name="colno">` says "output an element `<colno>`". I think you should use something like `<xsl:element name="{xpath/to/columnName}">`

edit:

According to your input xml your template for "COL" element should look like

```
<xsl:template match="COL">
    <xsl:variable name="colPosition" select="position()" />
    <!-- Prevent spaces in NAME attribute of FIELD element -->
    <xsl:variable name="colName" select="translate($kMetaData[$colPosition]/@NAME, ' ', '_')" />
    <xsl:element name="{$colName}">
        <xsl:value-of select="DATA"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Then the output looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PERSON>
    <ELEMENTS>
        <FIRSTNAME>Richard</FIRSTNAME>
        <LASTNAME>Katz</LASTNAME>
        <MIDDLENAME>David</MIDDLENAME>
        <REQUESTDT>1/1/2001</REQUESTDT>
        <salutation>Mr</salutation>
        <Bargaining_Unit>CSEA (02,03,04)</Bargaining_Unit>
        <Field_134>b</Field_134>
    </ELEMENTS>
</PERSON>
```

Comment: The output looks like:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  - <PERSON>
  - <ELEMENTS>
  <colno>Richard</colno>  
  <colno>Katz</colno> 
  <colno>David</colno> 
  <colno>1/1/2001</colno> 
  <colno>Mr</colno> 
  <colno>CSEA (02,03,04)</colno> 
  <colno>b</colno> 
  </ELEMENTS>
- <ELEMENTS>
  <colno>David</colno> 
  <colno>Norton</colno> 
  <colno>di</colno> 
  <colno>1/1/2011</colno> 
  <colno>Mr</colno> 
  <colno>UUP (08)</colno> 
  <colno /> etc,.   I want the <colno> to be the field names, like firstname, lastname, middlename, etc.  They are the variable fields.  Thank you for help.

Comment: What is your input xml?

Comment: The input data set looks like this: <METADATA>
<FIELD  NAME="FIRSTNAME" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
<FIELD  NAME="LASTNAME" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
<FIELD  NAME="MIDDLENAME" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
<FIELD  NAME="REQUESTDT" TYPE="DATE" /> 
<FIELD  NAME="salutation" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
<FIELD  NAME="Bargaining Unit" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
<FIELD  NAME="Field 134" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
  </METADATA>
<ROW>- <COL><DATA>Richard</DATA></COL>
- <COL><DATA>Katz</DATA> </COL>
- <COL><DATA>David</DATA></COL>
- <COL><DATA>1/1/2001</DATA></COL>
- <COL><DATA>Mr</DATA></COL>
- <COL><DATA>CSEA (02,03,04)</DATA></COL>
- <COL><DATA>b</DATA></COL></ROW>

Comment: We are close, but still not there.  Now, the problem seems to be reading the data from Filemaker.  When I use fmp:Col for the select and template, I get this output: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <PERSON>
  <ELEMENTS>RichardKatzDavid1/1/2001MrCSEA (02,03,04)b</ELEMENTS> 
  </PERSON>  The column names (the fields) disappeared.  Without the fmp, the record is empty.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here is the entire input xml:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
  <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE> 
  <PRODUCT BUILD="03-21-2013" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 12.0v4" /><DATABASE DATEFORMAT="M/d/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="UP2_TABLE.fmp12" RECORDS="6" TIMEFORMAT="h:mm:ss a" />- METADATA>
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="FIRSTNAME" TYPE="TEXT" /> <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="LASTNAME" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="MIDDLENAME" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
<FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="REQUESTDT" TYPE="DATE" />

Comment: <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="salutation" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
  <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Bargaining Unit" TYPE="TEXT" /> <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Field 134" TYPE="TEXT" /> 
  </METADATA>
- <RESULTSET FOUND="6">
- <ROW MODID="18" RECORDID="2">
- <COL>
  <DATA>Richard</DATA> 
  </COL>
- <COL>
  <DATA>Katz</DATA> 
  </COL>
- <COL>
  <DATA>David</DATA> 
  </COL>
- <COL>
  <DATA>1/1/2001</DATA> 
  </COL>
- <COL>
  <DATA>Mr</DATA> 
  </COL>
- <COL>
  <DATA>CSEA (02,03,04)</DATA> 
  </COL>
- <COL>
  <DATA>b</DATA> 
  </COL>
  </ROW>
</RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>

Comment: Ok, there are several problems: (a) as you have declared namespace in input xml, you have to use appropriate prefix in xsl (b) in template you declared xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" but in input xml it is  xmlns="filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" - they must be same in xml and xslt (c) the variable kMetaData should look like `<xsl:variable name="kMetaData" select="//fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD"/>` to be filled with data

Comment: After making those changes (actually I had figured out I was at a level above), I get the field labels, but no data:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <PERSON>
- <ELEMENTS>
  <FIRSTNAME /> 
  <LASTNAME /> 
  <MIDDLENAME /> 
  <REQUESTDT /> 
  <salutation /> 
  <Bargaining_Unit /> 
  <Field_134 /> 
  </ELEMENTS>
I am using FMP:COL for the template select and match.  We are so close!

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have namespace at value-of too? i.e. `<xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA"/>`

Comment: OMG.  When I put in the <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA"/> it worked like a charm! I wonder if there is somewhere here that I could post the whole code, since there are others following this conversation.  Thank you.  This is just wonderful!